# Запись предложений в файл java.io

Tags: java

С клавиатуры вводится слово. В первом файле найти все **предложения**, которые содержат введённое слово и записать их во второй файл.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your word: ");
    String word = in.next();
    try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Igor\\Dropbox\\Java\\Lab4_5\\file1.txt"))
    {
            int c;
            while((c=reader.read())!=-1) {

                    System.out.print((char)c);
            }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }



}
}
```

Не понимаю как дальше поделить файл на предложения(предположительно, методом split()) и реализовать поиск.

Comment: Никто не знает как поделить на предложения. Если только они не примитивные

Comment: Самые обычные предложения.

Answer (score 2):

для начала не надо выводить в консоль текст файла, вам же с ним ещё работать, так что записывайте его в массив или строку.

Как вариант использовать метод Files.readAllBytes():

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(путь к файлу)));
```

---

Если принципиально использовать java.io, то вот так:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
char[] buff = new char[1024];
try(Reader reader = new FileReader("путь к файлу")){
    int read;
    while( (read = reader.read(buff)) != 0) {
        builder.append(buff, 0, read);
    }
}
String text = builder.toString();
```

---

Дальше разделить строку по точке.

```
String[] offers = text.split("\\.");
```

Потом пройтись по всем предложениям и поверить наличие слова в них и положить все в список:

```
List<String> resultStrings = new ArrayList<>();
for (String offer : offers) {
    if (offer.contains("слово"))
        resultStrings.add(offer);
}
```

---

Это так же можно сделать в стримах java 8:

```
List<String> resultStrings = Arrays.stream(offers)
        .filter(s -> s.contains("слово"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Потом записать в файл например так же через Files.write():

```
Files.write(Paths.get("путь к файлу"), resultStrings, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
```

По последнему параметру StandardOpenOption можно [посмотреть документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)  и выбрать подходящую вам опцию (создать новый файл, перезаписать данные, дописать данные...)

Либо по старинке:

```
try(Writer writer = new FileWriter("путь к файлу")){
    for (String resultString : resultStrings) {
        writer.write(resultString);
    }
}
```